# Gradient of a function at a point

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have defined a function

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x*y^2 - y *z^2
```

and I want to evaluate its gradient at the point (0,-2,1)
I tried `Grad[f[x,y,z], {0,-2,1}]` and that just gave me back the function with a nabla in front of it.
I tried `Grad[f[0, -2, 1], {x, y, z}]`. That of course gives zero because `x`,`y` and `z` are constant, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x*y^2 - y*z^2

Grad[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]
```

> {y^2, 2 x y - z^2, -2 y z}

```
%/. {x -> 0, y -> -2, z -> 1}
```

> {4, -1, 4}

Answer (score 2):

Or you could make a second function

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x*y^2 - y*z^2

gradf[x_, y_, z_] = Grad[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}];

gradf[0, -2, 1]
(*{4, -1, 4}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `Derivative`:

```
Derivative[##][f][0, -2, 1] & @@@ IdentityMatrix[3]
```

> $\left\{f^{(1,0,0)}(0,-2,1),\,f^{(0,1,0)
>    }(0,-2,1),\,f^{(0,0,1)}(0,-2,1)\right
>    \}$

In your specific case:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x*y^2 - y*z^2    
Derivative[##][f][0, -2, 1] & @@@ IdentityMatrix[3]
```

> `{4, -1, 4}`